# webview loads webpage, but some contents get vanished after loading (Android Studio)

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

I tried to view http://artikelweb.com in a webview. The **web page appears nicely**. But, whenever I go to **any author link from "Popular Authors" section**, the web page appears, but, after loading, the **quotes aren't showing**.

In Google Chrome Browser(mobile) the quotes appear after loading,

[image: Mobile Chrome View is here]

but, in my app, the quotes are not showing in web view.

[image: My app view is here]

Code Snippet:

```
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_web);

    myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.artikelweb.com");
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());


}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(myWebView.canGoBack()) {
        myWebView.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: Use some library for Webview.
Check this link.[AdvancedWebview](https://github.com/delight-im/Android-AdvancedWebView)

Comment: Is the site yours? I really suggest to make the site stable before doing any other investigation on why it doesn't render well on android webview, Looking at it from a desktop PC it gives "something went wrong" too many times and sometimes once in your page give javascript errors like this `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked.

Comment: No.Its not mine.

Comment: Okay. I gave you the explanation why the default webview with your settings doesn't work. You must enable deh DOM Storage API https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your particular case you must enable the DOM Storage API

```
webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

So your code must become:

```
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_web);

    myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.artikelweb.com");
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
}
```

That becouse the javascript that use the website you are accessing needs it in its javascript.

[image]

[image]

Of course you could take advantage of a third party library, but again you won't know why this exact case works in the third party one and not in the default webview.

The library you are using has this initial settings:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/delight-im/Android-AdvancedWebView/master/Source/library/src/main/java/im/delight/android/webview/AdvancedWebView.java

```
final WebSettings webSettings = getSettings();
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(false);
        setAllowAccessFromFileUrls(webSettings, false);
        webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 18) {
            webSettings.setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
        }
        webSettings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
            webSettings.setDatabasePath(databaseDir);
        }
        setMixedContentAllowed(webSettings, true);

        setThirdPartyCookiesEnabled(true);
```

Enabling by default many options that the default webview has disable for security reason.

Comment: thanks a lot for your information. :) 
It helped to get the clear idea of the problem.

Comment: @Sayem Happy to help! Hope you’ll upvote my answer when you can ;)

Comment: @Sayem okay! So l’ll be w8ing ;)

Comment: @Sayem This should be the right answer. Remember that you could always change your answer decision if another one It's better than another or more specific to the presented subject. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Set UserAgent to your Webview settings and try

```
webSettings.setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; <Android Version>; <Build Tag etc.>) AppleWebKit/<WebKit Rev> (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/<Chrome Rev> Mobile Safari/<WebKit Rev>");
```