# Webview doesn't load AdSense ads

Tags: android, webview, ads

I'm doing a webview application. I have a problem: "Adsense ads appear when using Chrome custom tabs, but adsense ads don't appear when using regular webview."
In normal webview, how are ads allowed?

Example İmage

[image: Example İmage]

```
   CookieSyncManager.createInstance(getActivity());
    CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
    cookieManager.acceptCookie();
    cookieManager.acceptThirdPartyCookies(webView);
    cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
    CookieSyncManager.createInstance(getActivity());
    CookieSyncManager.getInstance().startSync();

    webView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
    webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
    webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
```

webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4; Nexus 5 Build/*BuildID*) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/30.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36");
        String url = "http://solante.pw";
        webView.loadUrl(url);

Comment: show the webview code

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko i add the code

Comment: try setting some chrome-like user agent. Probably they don't allow ad for webview default user agent

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko how can i this?

Comment: 1) get the chrome user-agent. 2) google out how to set custom user-agent for webview. 3) do what you've found

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko I did. It's not working.

Comment: take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48515359/webview-loads-webpage-but-some-contents-get-vanished-after-loading-android-stu/48523030#48523030

Comment: @shadowsheep I tried all the suggestions, but it didn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This maybe a too late answer!
I hope it will help someone.

After some research I tried this solution and it works fine for me.
Just try to set up a desktop user agent to your webview

```
String DESKTOP_USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2049.0 Safari/537.36";
webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(DESKTOP_USER_AGENT);
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply add this line to your code

```
 webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```